# Extract text between two strings in simple example.html file

Tags: html, bash, awk

I have a very basic html file called `example.html` (see below)

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="one">
    <div class="research">
        <div class="two">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I'd like to get only phrase like (see below), but not by removing first and last 3 lines.

```
<div class="research">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried with `awk`:

```
cat example.html | awk '/^<div\ class="research">$/,/^<\/div>$/ { print }'
```

but something seems to be wrong.

I also tried with `body` tag (see below)

```
cat example.html | awk '/^<body>$/,/^<\/body>$/ { print }'
```

(result)

```
<body>
<div class="one">
    <div class="research">
        <div class="two">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
```

And it's working correctly.

What I've doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/^<div class="research">$/` doesn't work because `<div` isn't at the beginning of the line, and `^` matches the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yeah! You have right, but still the last `</div>` are in the game. So the question is how to select text to proper ending `div` tag?

Comment: You need to count all the matching <div> and </div> tags. You can't do this with a simple `first,last` pattern, you have to write `awk` code to increment a counter when you see another `<div>`, and decrement it when you see a `</div>`. When the counter goes to 0, you've matched the first one.

Comment: As an aside, avoid the [Useless Use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [cannot parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Assuming the html is valid xml, you can use:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//div[@class="research"]' -nl example.html
```

```
<div class="research">
        <div class="two">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: +1 You cannot parse HTML with regular expressions. (I just like repeating that).